# Java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: localhost

Tags: java, rmi

So i have read up on similar questions but i haven't found anything that i fully understand yet.

http://www.coderanch.com/t/487650/java/java/java-rmi-ConnectException-Connection-refused

http://protegewiki.stanford.edu/wiki/Troubleshooting_Client_Server_Connections

[what is RMI registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658929/what-is-rmi-registry)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/faq.html#domain

I have a server which is crashing every few days and I am trying to work out where the problem lies. The software is running in an environment supplied by the customer and i need to know if we are the problem or windows/the network.

My question is... RMI registry,  Is that something that java creates or is it something that exists in windows anyway? Why would a connection to localhost suddenly become unavailable or refused? Is there anything that i can do to troubleshoot immediately?

The RMI configuration is here:

```
<RMIService>
        <class>com.s.i.system.RMIService</class>
        <server name="Server">
            <host>localhost</host>
            <timeout>0</timeout>
        </server>
    </RMIService>
```

Here is the error that is created in the logs.

```
2015-04-02 16:52:10,057 ERROR [main] com...........gui.initialise.ClientInitialise - java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: localhost; nested exception is: 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
at java.rmi.Naming.lookup(Unknown Source)
at com.s.i.system.RMIService.lookup(RMIService.java:570)
at com.s.i.system.RMIService.lookupServer(RMIService.java:377)
at com.s.i.process.RemoteRequestHandler$Dispatcher.run(RemoteRequestHandler.java:282)
at com.s.i.process.RemoteRequestHandler$Dispatcher.start(RemoteRequestHandler.java:269)
at com.s.i.process.RemoteRequestHandler.handle(RemoteRequestHandler.java:96)
at com.s.i.process.RequestDispatcher.dispatch(RequestDispatcher.java:136)
at com.s.i.client.ClientInitialiser.initialiseEnvironment(ClientInitialiser.java:498)
at com.s.i.client.ClientInitialiser.performEnvironmentInit(ClientInitialiser.java:145)
at com.s.i.client.ClientInitialiser.initialise(ClientInitialiser.java:128)
at com.s.i.client.ClientInitialiser.initialise(ClientInitialiser.java:106)
at com.s.i.gui.initialise.ClientInitialise.createInitialiser(ClientInitialise.java:136)
at com.s.i.gui.initialise.ClientInitialise.<init>(ClientInitialise.java:155)
at com.s.i.client.Client.initialise(Client.java:118)
at com.s.i.client.Client.main(Client.java:147)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(Unknown Source)
... 20 more
```

Answer (score 1):

The RMI Registry is a component of the JRE, not of Windows. Clearly it is crashing, or far more probably it is being closed down incorrectly for some reason. I've never seen an RMI Registry crash in 18 years.